# & (and) in inner-function, do the top level functions inherit it?

Tags: php, variables

```
function clean($data, &$user) { //<- do I need to have the and here as well?
    $dataB = coolStuff($user); 
    return dataA * $dataB;
}



function coolStuff(&$user){
return $user++;
}
```

Do I need to have the & in front of my function carried onto the top level function as well?

Comment: Sorry, question was wrongly stated, I've updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has to be in any function where you want a reference to the object rather than a copy. Example:

```
function clean($data, &$user) {
    $dataB = coolStuff($user);
    return $data * $dataB;
}

function coolStuff(&$user) {
    return $user++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to, if you want to have &user to be changed outside the clean() function too.